# Setting the Background colour of individual rows separately in a Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a Listview which lists jobs in my Android app. I want to colour the rows according to their job type. Below is the code I use to set up the Listview.

```
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.menu_item, cursor, FROM, TO);
    menuList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Below is the Xml layout for the Listview items.

```
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:padding="10sp">
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/rowid"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="@color/exhibitor_header" /> 
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/rowidtwo"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="@color/listview_background"
      android:layout_below="@+id/rowid"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I set the Listview to display each row in the colour relating to it's job category. Can I do it without using a custom adapter?

Comment: i think you cant do it without a custom adapter...
you have to write your own SimpleCursorAdapter...

Comment: Use custom adapter for that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for you: [Android – Applying Alternate Row Color in ListView with SimpleAdapter](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/).

Define a custom adapter same as the above example, and you have to put a condition to check job type inside the `getView()` method and based on that you can apply different background color.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I've added a custom adapter using the following code  public Lectures_Adapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> items, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, items, resource, from, to);
        this.data = items;
    }   When I try to call it I get an error when I try to amend the example to using my data. My data is from a Sqlite table and loaded into a cursor. The error wants me to change cursor by casting it as List<HashMap<String, String>>

Comment: I've sorted it out, my adapter was extending SimpleAdapter instead of SimpleCursorAdapter but your solution worked for me. Thank You